# Plot shows different answer for the similar arguments

Tags: plotting

I've just started to learn Mathematica so forgive me if it's a simple question. I'm trying to find out why `Plot` that contains expression with `ReplaceAll` works different from `Plot` with `Set` . I have:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
I0[t_] = HeavisidePi[(t - 1/2 10^-9)/10^-9];
sol = DSolve[{D[I2[t], t]*R == I1[t]/C0, I0[t] == I1[t] + I2[t], 
    I2[0] == 0}, {I1[t], I2[t]}, t];
I2 = I2[t] /. sol[[1]];
Plot[I2 /. {C0 -> 5*10^-12, R -> 500}, {t, -2 10^-9, 10^-8}]
C0 = 5*10^-12;
R = 500;
Plot[I2, {t, -2 10^-9, 10^-8}]
```

For some reason first plot gives the right answer and the second one wrong. I expected same answers. What is the reason for the difference?

Comment: I think you may have a precision problem.  Mathematica does the computation for the plot at machine precision, and I suspect that you have rounding errors somewhere.  You may get better results if you `Simplify` `I2`

Comment: As suggested by @mikado, `I2 = FullSimplify[I2[t] /. sol[[1]]]` resolves the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You are evaluating a symbolic solution with a real input, which in this case is causing some problems.

Try obtaining the symbolic solution before applying real inputs.

```
sol = DSolve[{D[I2[t], t]*R == I1[t]/C0, I0[t] == I1[t] + I2[t],
    I2[0] == 0}, {I1[t], I2[t]}, t];
I0[t_] = HeavisidePi[(t - 1/2 10^-9)/10^-9];
I2 = I2[t] /. sol[[1]];
Plot[I2 /. {C0 -> 5*10^-12, R -> 500}, {t, -2 10^-9, 10^-8}]
```

[image]

Note, `I2` does not simplify.

[image]

Comment: Note what happens when you include `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` in the third definition, i.e.,  `I2 = Simplify[I2[t] /. sol[[1]]];`

Comment: @BobHanlon Same result, as long as `sol` is evaluated before `I0`.

Comment: My apologies, I cannot reproduce the result that I got earlier. I must have had an old definition laying around.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way:

```
I0[t_] := HeavisideTheta[(t - 1/2 1*^-9)/1*^-9]
(* note that I have already eliminated I1[t] *)
sol = With[{R = 500, C0 = 5*^-12}, 
           DSolveValue[{I2'[t] == (I0[t] - I2[t])/(R C0), I2[0] == 0}, I2, t]];

Plot[sol[t], {t, -2*^-9, 1*^-8}]
```

[image: plot of solution]

Strangely, I get a different result if I try to replace `HeavisidePi[]` with `UnitBox[]`…